# number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{5}\times\mathbb{Z}_{5}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I have to show that the number of subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{5}\times\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ (other than identity and itself)
is six, but I am a bit confused. please help!

P.S. can someone also tell if there is some method to determine the subgroups of direct products of cyclic groups?

Answer (score 3):

The subgroups you are looking for must have order 5. In particular, they are cyclic. The elements $(0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)$ each generate one of these subgroups.